# Construyendo un timeline con mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de control de lotes en `Bootstrap` con `AdminLTE`. Quiero establecer un *`timeline`* vertical para mostrar la trazabilidad de cada lote, a lo largo del tiempo. La idea es que cada vez que se haya producido un evento (inicio del lote, alimentación, finalización, incidencia, etc.), me muestre la fecha y la información sobre el evento.

La complejidad la he encontrado al almacenar la información en diversas tablas `mysql`, e intentar recuperar la información y mostrarla. Mi consulta es para conocer cuál sería la forma más eficiente de obtener la información, y mostrarla en un *`timeline`*.

Por ahora, he obtenido algunos avances con `JOIN`, pero me he quedado estancado.

Mi principal problema es mostrar, para un mismo lote, fechas obtenidas de diversas tablas, que muestren además los eventos:

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT bi.L3beddate, fee.feeddate AS date, fee.foodkg, fee.foodmix AS foodmix, fee.feedremark AS feedremark
FROM batchinput bi
INNER JOIN feeding fee
ON bi.batchnumber = fee.batchnumber 
WHERE bi.batchnumber = 'COL-01-02'";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

?>

<html>  
    <head>  
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/timeline.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/timeline.min.css" />
  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">
   <br />

   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="timeline">
                  <div class="timeline__wrap">
                   <div class="timeline__items">
                   <?php 
                   foreach($result as $row)
                   {
                   ?>
                    <div class="timeline__item">
                     <div class="timeline__content">
                      <h2>Fecha: <?php echo $row["date"]; ?></h2>
                      <p><?php echo $row["foodkg"];?> Kg de alimento de la dieta <?php echo $row["foodmix"];?></p>
                      <p><?php echo $row["feedremark"];?></p>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                   <?php
                   }
                   ?>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Las tablas mysql son:

```html
La que define los lotes: 
| batchinput | CREATE TABLE `batchinput` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batchnumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `batchoriginal` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `batchtype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `batchactive` enum('SI','NO') NOT NULL,
  `batchinfo` text NOT NULL,
  `L3beddate` date NOT NULL,
  `L5enddate` date NOT NULL,
  
La que define la alimentación:
  | feeding | CREATE TABLE `feeding` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feeddate` date NOT NULL,
  `batchnumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batchegg` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foodkg` float NOT NULL,
  `foodmix` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `feedaction` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedremark` text NOT NULL,

La que define incidencias en el sistema:
| remarks | CREATE TABLE `remarks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `remarkdate` date NOT NULL,
  `batchnumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batchremark` text NOT NULL,
  `process` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un dataset con un ejemplo concreto de lo que necesitas?

Comment: ¿Y los datos? :)